# where can I install VM agent for VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I just followed an instruction to create a VM, and it says "Tick Install the VM Agent", but I couldn't find this option in the VM I created:

[image]

There was no such option for "Tick Install the VM Agent" during the install of the VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created an ARM vm, not ASM vm. ([read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-model))

ARM vm's have VM agent on them by default, so its already there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if I switch to the old portal, I could not find all the VMs I created in new portal, is it normal? How can I connect to VM under the new portal?

Comment: yes, this is perfectly fine, just read about ARM vs ASM, they differ a lot, to connect to a VM you should press the connect button, which is not surprising @grooveline

Comment: Under the new portal, you can see the connect button is inactive in the picture, so how I can login in the VM?